# How to use spray in ocean modifier

Tags: modifiers, ocean-simulation

ocean modifier after blender 2.90 has a new feature called the spray in foam subpanel,and I have no idea how to use the spray direction map it gives me.

Comment: Don't know if [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0ch1-aovuM) YT video helps?

Comment: @JohnEason That clip is for an add-on, so not totally relevant here

Answer (score 3):

One way is combination of "Ocean" and "GeometryNodes".
the "Foam" and "Spray" both are attribute, they can pass through Geometry Input into GeometryNodes process.

[image: Ocean Spray Example]

Ocean is great.

Comment: This is a very powerful answer, thank you!  I wish you went into a bit more technical detail but I can certainly reverse engineer what you've done and I'm going to dabble. Cheers!