# spray option in the ocean modifier?

Tags: materials, shaders, ocean-simulation

I've been trying for days to figure out the spray option in the ocean modifier... I'm pretty new to blender and there's like one little question here with a very short answer which I didn't understand... Any of you know how?

Comment: are you referring to this question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233048/how-to-use-spray-in-ocean-modifier

Comment: Yes that’s the one